# Process: System usage at about 30%. WPA shows unkown process

Tags: windows-10, cpu-usage

**Solution**: I dug a bit deeper in WPA and at least found a name. It was in the same dropdown menu that has 25% usage (at the time of recording). Although WPA said it had to do with a kernal driver, I instead looked for the the other named driver in the dropdown, which was part of Avast.

Going down said rabbit hole and a couple more google searches, I found "Prcoess Explorer". Said tool was actually able to see what is wrong. I downloaded the Windows 10 SDK developer tools to get access to the threads in the detailed view on process explorer and the thing that's bugging my CPU is actually Avast. It is exactly the same problem as described here:

https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=228004.0

So let's hope Avast really does fix it with 19.10, because atm its still on 19.8. For now I guess I will just restart occasionally when this problem appears. Thanks to everyone trying to help me out.

---

So I was playing Minecraft when I noticed that its lagging quite a bit. I looked up my Task Manager and saw that the System process hogged 30% CPU.

After some googling I found out about the performance analysis tool of Win 10 SDK. I used that to record 1 minute of CPU usage and analyzed it in WPA (Windows Performance Analyzer).

My Problem is that these previous answered questions always said to look in the CPU Usage (sampled) tab. In that tab the Idle process is 99.xx% and System uses almost nothing.

But in the CPU Usage (precise) tab, I can see that the CPU uses the 25-30% it shows in the task manager. But when I open the details I expected to see a driver acting up. But instead it says "Unknown".

Is there any way to find out what it is thats causing the high CPU usage?

Specs:

- Intel i5-3570K
- 16GB DDR3 RAM
- Geforce 980 GTX.

**Notes:**
I recently upgraded from Win 7 to Win 10. I did a complete format of my system drive and installed a clean Win 10 on it. I didnt install any drivers aside from mouse (Logitech), keyboard (steelseries) and graphics (NVIDIA). On Win 7 I usually had to install main board drivers for sound and LAN, but it all worked from the getgo with Win 10. Aside from that I used Avast as protection coupled witht he Win 10 firewall and "Win 10 Firewall control". Im about to run a full scan with malwarebytes tonight and see if something comes up.

Comment: Run Windows Admin Tools, Resource Monitor and make sure you expand CPU, Disk and Network bars to see what is going on in all three, particularly Disk if the game is lagging and CPU is OK.

Comment: can you share the etl?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I found out it's Avast that has the problem. Digging deeper into Taks manager options and WPA helped in finding more concrete answers. Process Explorer was able to determine the problem in the end.